# How can I only display top comments for Google+?

Tags: google-plus, firefox, google-chrome

Is there an extension (for Chrome or Firefox) that allows viewing of comments only with only a certain number of votes for a post on Google+? I am considering writing one myself, but if it already exists, then there'd be no point.

Comment: I think you can go ahead with writing one yourself, there isn't any from scouring the Chrome Web store.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about only showing the top rated comments, but there are plenty of plugins that can collapse the comments out of your feed. I think you may have found a great idea for a plugin to write. Just in case you want to test them out, here's a couple of the ones that I found:

1. G+me
2. Google+ Ultimate for Google Plus
3. Usability Boost for Google Plus™
4. Google Plus Enhancer

These are all really customizable, and there may be ways to achieve what you're talking about within them.

Comment: These may now be broken to varying degrees, as the Goog have already added their own method for collapsing comments on Google+.